# Is it true that any time duration longer than 1 year of HTTP res header directive `Cache-Control max-age` consider invalid

Tags: caching, https, cache-control, max-age

I came cross a case where the `Cache-Control: public, max-age=31622400, immutable` which make 366 days, however it seems the best practice to be not greater than `31536000` which makes it 365 days, my question is, is the `max-age` considered invalid date if the number of seconds is 366days or more? also will be helpful if you can refer links or docs

Answer (score 0):

There is no particular limit on the value of `max-age`. You can see that in the RFC definition of [`max-age`](https://httpwg.org/specs/rfc9111.html#cache-request-directive.max-age) (and [delta-seconds](https://httpwg.org/specs/rfc9111.html#delta-seconds)).

The reason people sometimes use a one-year limit is that an [old version](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2616#section-14.21) of the specification limited the expiration time given by the `Expires` header:

> To mark a response as "never expires," an origin server sends an
> `Expires` date approximately one year from the time the response is
> sent. HTTP/1.1 servers SHOULD NOT send `Expires` dates more than one
> year in the future.

This is what the [current specification](https://httpwg.org/specs/rfc9111.html#field.expires) says on that subject:

> Historically, HTTP required the `Expires` field value to be no more than a year in the future. While longer freshness lifetimes are no longer prohibited, extremely large values have been demonstrated to cause problems (e.g., clock overflows due to use of 32-bit integers for time values), and many caches will evict a response far sooner than that.